# How to do subtraction of fields in the same column - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following initial dataframe :

[image]

```
Country      Gender     Q1
Australia    M          Increase
Australia    F          Increase
Australia    M          Increase
Australia    M          Decrease
India        M          Decrease
India        F          Increase
India        M          Decrease
South Africa F          Decrease
UK           F          Increase
```

Here we are counting Q1 for each filter :

[image]

```
Country       Gender      Q1         Count(Q1)
Australia       M         Increase    2
Australia       F         Increase    1
Australia       M         Decrease    1
India           M         Decrease    2
India           F         Increase    1
South Africa    F         Decrease    1
UK              F         Increase    1
```

Now for the same filter , I need to subtract the count(increase) with count(decrease)ans store in a new option in Q1 "Net". Thus Net = count(increase) - count(decrease).
The final dataframe looks like that :

[image]

Is this feasible in Python ?

Regards,

Comment: Hello! With pandas, yes is possible. I suggest you to give it a try, and come back if you encounter any difficulty showing your effort. Moreover, it's better to provide data as text and not as an image, so people can easily grab them and try their solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exactly what you wanted**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['Australia','Australia','Australia','Australia',
              'India','India','India',
              'South Africa','UK'],
    'Gender':['M','F','M','M',
             'M','F','M',
             'F','F'],
    'Q1':['Increase','Increase','Increase','Decrease',
          'Decrease','Increase','Decrease',
          'Decrease','Increase']
})
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Country','Gender','Q1'])['Q1']\
                   .count()).rename(columns={'Q1':'CountQ1'}).reset_index()
df2 =pd.pivot_table(df,index = ['Country','Gender'],
                  columns = 'Q1',
                  values = 'Q1',
                  aggfunc = lambda x: len(x),
                  margins_name = 'Q1').fillna(0).reset_index().copy()

df2 = df2.assign(CountQ1 = df2.Increase - df2.Decrease,
           Q1='Net',
           Net = df2.apply(lambda x: f'({int(x.Increase)}-{int(x.Decrease)})',axis=1))\
.drop(['Increase','Decrease'],axis=1)
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values(['Country','Gender'],ascending=(1,0))[['Country','Gender','Q1','CountQ1','Net']]
df3
```

**Output**

```
        Country Gender        Q1  CountQ1    Net
1     Australia      M  Decrease      1.0    NaN
2     Australia      M  Increase      2.0    NaN
1     Australia      M       Net      1.0  (2-1)
0     Australia      F  Increase      1.0    NaN
0     Australia      F       Net      1.0  (1-0)
4         India      M  Decrease      2.0    NaN
3         India      M       Net     -2.0  (0-2)
3         India      F  Increase      1.0    NaN
2         India      F       Net      1.0  (1-0)
5  South Africa      F  Decrease      1.0    NaN
4  South Africa      F       Net     -1.0  (0-1)
6            UK      F  Increase      1.0    NaN
5            UK      F       Net      1.0  (1-0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a default_count column to the initial dataframe and then use pivot_table

```
   df=pd.DataFrame({'country':['Australia','Australia','Australia','Australia','India','India','India','South Africa','UK'],'gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M','F','F'],'Q1':['Increase','Increase','Increase','Decrease','Decrease','Increase','Decrease','Decrease','Increase'],'default_count':['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1']})

   df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index=['country','gender'],columns='Q1',aggfunc='count',values='default_count').reset_index().fillna(0)

   df_pivot['Net']=df_pivot['Increase']-df_pivot['Decrease']
```

Comment: You can pass `fill_value=0` to `pivot_table` so that `df_pivot` has type `int` and looks better.